# no onCharacteristicChanged callbacks received from TI SensorTag

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have a TI Sensor Tag that I'm trying to interface with Android using BLE. I'm following the instructions here: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/SensorTag_User_Guide#SensorTag_Android_Development and things work up until the last step, I am not receiving onCharacteristicChanged callbacks.  Note: I do receive ONE onCharacteristicWrite callback, but nothing after that. Please help!

At first I thought this might be due to the synchronous callbacks & queue issue explained in the instructions, but I implemented that and it didn't solve the problem.

Applicable classes of my code: https://github.com/bhadley/ble_testing/tree/master/src/com/example/helloworld

```
D/BtGatt.GattService(  771): onGetDescriptor() - address=BC:6A:29:AC:72:D9, stat
us=0, descUuid=00002901-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt( 3500): onGetDescriptor() - Device=BC:6A:29:AC:72:D9 UUID=000029
01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BtGatt.btif(  771): btif_gattc_get_descriptor
D/BtGatt.btif(  771): btgattc_handle_event: Event 1010
D/BtGatt.GattService(  771): onGetDescriptor() - address=BC:6A:29:AC:72:D9, stat
us=133, descUuid=00002901-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt( 3500): onSearchComplete() = Device=BC:6A:29:AC:72:D9 Status=0
I/BLE     ( 3500): onServicesDiscovered
D/BluetoothGatt( 3500): writeCharacteristic() - uuid: f000aa32-0451-4000-b000-00
0000000000
D/BtGatt.GattService(  771): writeCharacteristic() - address=BC:6A:29:AC:72:D9
D/BtGatt.btif(  771): btif_gattc_write_char
D/BtGatt.btif(  771): btgattc_handle_event: Event 1015
D/BluetoothGatt( 3500): setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: f000aa31-0451-40
00-b000-000000000000 enable: true
D/BtGatt.GattService(  771): registerForNotification() - address=BC:6A:29:AC:72:
D9 enable: true
D/BtGatt.btif(  771): btif_gattc_reg_for_notification
D/BtGatt.btif(  771): btgattc_handle_event: Event 1018
D/BluetoothGatt( 3500): writeDescriptor() - uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f
9b34fb
D/BtGatt.GattService(  771): onRegisterForNotifications() - address=null, status
=0, registered=1, charUuid=f000aa31-0451-4000-b000-000000000000
D/BtGatt.GattService(  771): writeDescriptor() - address=BC:6A:29:AC:72:D9
D/BtGatt.btif(  771): btif_gattc_write_char_descr
D/BtGatt.btif(  771): btgattc_handle_event: Event 1016
E/bt-btif (  771): already has a pending command!!
I/BLE     ( 3500): status of enabling magnetometer notifications: true
D/BtGatt.btif(  771): btif_gattc_upstreams_evt: Event 4
D/BtGatt.GattService(  771): onWriteCharacteristic() - address=BC:6A:29:AC:72:D9
, status=0
D/BluetoothGatt( 3500): onCharacteristicWrite() - Device=BC:6A:29:AC:72:D9 UUID=
f000aa32-0451-4000-b000-000000000000 Status=0
I/BLE     ( 3500): onCharacteristicWrite
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some great help I received, I found the problems that fixed my issues:

1) needed to wait for the sensor to turn on THEN enable notifications (originally I called them sequentially without a pause) and this caused the error: already has a pending command!!

2) The correct flag for notifications for TI SensorTag is BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE (I had an incorrect tag in previously)

3) I had to implement a queue to schedule callbacks to prevent the pending command callback. Thanks to Steven Rudenko for some amazing help with that!

Data is coming in through the onCharacteristicChanged callback now!

Comment: Did you have any issue where onCharacteristicWrite is *never* called?  I get the connection callback, I get the services discovered callback, I even get onDescriptorWrite callbacks....but no onCharacteristicWrite callbacks.

Comment: @MattC I have the same problem you do.